# Hot to add xml tag at the start of file and at the end

Tags: php, xml

I've got broken data.xml file, how i can fix it with php?
I need to add at the beginning of the file two lines

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archive>
...<xml data>...
```

And at the end of the file

```
</archive>
```

Does anyone have any ideas or solutions how to add and save xml structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sort of an incomplete questions... Are you writing a script to run on the command-line and work with files?  Handling uploaded files?

In general just treat the file as a text file.  You can make a new file, write your new first two lines, then output the contents of your data.xml file, then write the last line.  It's just text.